# Find length of side

Tags: geometry, triangles, rectangles

I tried to solve this problem ... but i can't find answer.

Anyone can help me?

```
EBC=90 & DCB=90 & AHC=AHB=90
```

[image]

Comment: I am confused by the condition $B=C=H=90$

Comment: @Peter EBC is 90 & DCB=90 & AHC=AHB=90

Comment: @Peter i add what B=C=H=90 means in question.

Comment: Sorry ... :( DC = 3

Comment: @Peter I was changed image of problem

Comment: @AlexSilva I was changed image of problem

Comment: @Peter it is all of informations about problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is ill-posed. Notice that $\Delta EBC \sim \Delta AHC$ and $\Delta DCB \sim \Delta AHB$. Thus,

$\frac{2}{BC} = \frac{1}{HC}$, and $\frac{3}{BC} = \frac{1}{BH}$.

Hence,

$HC + BH  = \frac{BC}{2}+ \frac{BC}{3} = \frac{5}{6}BC \neq BC.$ (???)

Comment: Why ΔEBC≅ΔAHC and ΔDCB≅ΔAHB.  ?

Comment: Because they are similar. Sorry, I've changed the notation.

Comment: Why you put (???) at end of your answer?

Comment: @alex you are right. The conditions cannot be simultaneously met, so you can remove the question marks.

Comment: @MohammadGholamian, just for showing that this problem is inconsistent!

Comment: @AlexSilva in **ΔEBC∼ΔAHC** we know AHC=EBC And C is common, but why HAC = BEC? Is this is geometric?

Comment: @AlexSilva Are you say this problem is inconsistent and hasn't answer?

Comment: @mohammad yes, he does and he is right. Draw a picture and measure the lengths. You will see that they cannot be $1,2,3$ in the way it is required unless CD is on the same side as EB.

Comment: @Peter When we don't have BC length how i draw picture and measure lengths?

Comment: @MohammadGholamian, it is just a consequence of Thales' theorem.

Comment: What I meant, try to draw the picture in the way above, such that the lengths are $1,2,3$.

Comment: @Peter, Did you mean A and D coincides?

Comment: If CD would be left from EB, we would have an infinity of solutions. Notice that the two triangles are decoupled.

Comment: @Peter, if $ AH=HC=1$, we wouldn't need the $\Delta DCB$.

Comment: OK, probably this is not meant.